# What is the difference between "send something somewhere" and "send something in somewhere"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between *send something somewhere* and *send something in somewhere*? For example:

> You should defintely **send** the tape to a music company.
>
> You should defintely **send** the tape **in** to a music company.

Comment: I think you might have asked more than once about what's effectively the same aspect of English. There are ***many, many*** contexts where it's perfectly okay to include ***optional additional prepositions***. So long as both versions (with and without the extraneous preposition) are fairly common, they'll usually carry the same meaning. But we always tend to look for / create semantic distinctions wherever there are multiple ways of phrasing something. So *eventually*, people start to differentiate *Ringo Starr **of** The Beatles* from *Ringo Starr **out of** The Beatles*.

Comment: In your case, also *You should definitely send the tape **out** to a music company* and *You should definitely send the tape **off** to a music company* (not to mention ***over to, up to***, and possibly others). To all intents and purposes, they're all the same.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I'm confused though because in the movie "Back To the Future" Jennifer said "send the tape in to the company"

Comment: I hope you meant you ***were*** confused, not that you're ***still*** confused. Preposition ***to*** needs to be present, because it indicates "movement" (***from*** addressee ***to*** company). An additional optional preposition *(**in, out, over, up,...**)* simply adds an element of clarification (perhaps partly or entirely metaphorical) regarding direction / orientation of travel. So perhaps *Send it **up** to them* might imply they're more "elevated" (you do lowly music-making, they do "higher status" *publishing*). Or *Send it **down** to them* to imply they're the lower-status party!

Comment: ...or ***up / down*** might simply be because they're located further North / South, OR are at a higher / lower elevation, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, "send in" carries a connotation of "submitting," like "submitting paperwork" or "submitting an entry for a contest." In the context of "Back to the Future," this would make sense, since Jennifer is suggesting that Marty submit his tape to a music company for them to listen and possibly offer him an opportunity. Omitting "in" here would be perfectly fine as well, but would not carry this connotation of "submitting."

You wouldn't use "send in" for other situations like

> You should send the letter <s>in</s> to your grandmother.